# How to unbold "Theorem", "Corollary" and "Lemma" titles

Tags: bold, article

I am using an article document class and I need to "unbold" all titles of theorems, corollaries, lemmas and remarks. How can I do this. Any Help?

Comment: Theorems/corollaries/lemmas are not predefined environments in the `article` class. We need a MWE to know how you are setting them up.

Comment: Using \newtheorem environment

Answer (score 1):

Theorems defined by LaTeX's standard `\newtheorem` macro have always a bold heading, because they expand to something like

```
\trivlist \item[\hskip\labelsep {\bfseries <theorem name & counter>}]
```

You might use packages like `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to customize your theorem-like environments. Alternatively you can patch the macros `\@begintheorem` and `\@opargbegintheorem` (the latter is for theorems with an optional argument) which are called with theorem-like environments defined by the standard format:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```